# should I normalise data of disparate frequencies

Tags: neural-network, cnn, statistics, preprocessing, normalization

The dataset consists of rows of time series data. Most of the time data remains constant and only updates when there are significant changes. Each time series looks something like this
[image]
where each vertical line is a curve before being automatically rescaled.

I am preprocessing the data to input to a CNN model, thus I am thinking about normalising the data. But I am concerned about 2 issues:

1) The frequencies of data: most data are around 25 vs very little data between 25-45

2) The magnitude of data: although very little data is between 25-45, they are significantly greater than the rest(about twice the magnitude).

As such, given data is not normally distributed(maybe partially uniform?),I am not sure if it is valid to do normalisation. Please shed some light. Any help is appreciated.